# Creating new array with contents from old array while keeping the old array static

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have an array of integers,

```
int[] array = new int[7];
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
array[i] = i;
}
```

Now i want to get only the first four numbers in that `array`, and turn put that into another array.

So I really want something like...

```
newArray = array[0-3].
```

I know that syntax is wrong, but I'm just giving the general idea of what I'm trying to do, is anything like that possible? Or do i have to create a loop and add it manually into the `newArray`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
int[] newArr = new int[4];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArr, 0, 4);
```

The method takes five arguments:

1. `src`: The source array.
2. `srcPosition`: The position in the source from where you wish to begin
   copying.
3. `des`: The destination array.
4. `desPosition`: The position in the destination array to where the copy
   should start.
5. `length`: The number of elements to be copied.

This method throws a NullPointerException if either of src or des are null. 
It also throws an ArrayStoreException in the following cases:

- If the src is not an array.
- If the des is not an array.
- If src and des are arrays of different data types.

**Method 2**

Utilize

`Arrays.copyOf(array,4)` to copy the first 4 elements, truncating the rest.

of

`Arrays.copyOfRange(array,1,5)` to copy elements 1-4 if you need the middle of an array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for your last method 2, Arrays.copyOfRange(array,1,5) will copy elements 1-4. I dont know why they made it like that... but thanks for your response, i'm def. using the last method

Answer (score 12):

```
int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(array,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create the new array in the size you want (4 in this case), and then use [System.arrayCopy](http://www.kiwidoc.com/java/l/p/java/j2se/1.6/p/java.lang/c/System#arraycopy%28Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;II%29) to copy the contents from one array to another.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [copyOfRange](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) for this purpose,which Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array.

```
copyOfRange(byte[] original,
                 int from,
                 int to)
```

---

Parameters:

> original - the array from which a range is to be copied
>
> from     - the initial index of the range to be copied, **inclusive**
>
> to       - the final index of the range to be copied, **exclusive**. (This index may lie outside the array.)