# I have a problem with Arraylist here it is overwrite the last object (called "Queen") I add to evreything in Arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist, overwrite

```
    public class Queen {

    static int QueenPos[];
    public int her;
    int N;

     public Queen() {

     }
    public Queen(int[] queenPos) {
        this.QueenPos=queenPos;
        this.her = getHer();
        this.N=getQueenPos().length;
    }

    public static int[] getQueenPos() {
      return QueenPos;
    }

    public static void setQueenPos(int queenPos[]) {
      QueenPos = queenPos;
    }
```

in this function i add object Queen in Arraylist and I have overwrite problem in the arraylist

```
  public static ArrayList<Queen> GenarateQueen (Queen q,int col){
    ArrayList<Queen> gen=new ArrayList<Queen>() ;


    for (int i = 0; i < q.QueenPos.length; i++) {
        int g [] = q.getQueenPos();
        g[col]=i;
        gen.add(i,new Queen(g));
        int a[]=gen.get(i).QueenPos;
        int r=0;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < gen.size(); i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < gen.get(i).QueenPos.length; k++) {
          System.out.print(" | "+gen.get(i).QueenPos[k]+" | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }               
    return gen;
  }
```

Comment: Why is `QueenPos` static? Given that it is, why on earth would you make the *constructor* replace that **global** array every time a new `Queen` object is created? Remove `static`!!!

Comment: I try and remove static but the problem still exists :(

Comment: @Duha Can you give an example as well of what you have tried and what result do you expect ?

Comment: I create object Queen q with QueenPos={0,1,2,0} And passed it to function GenareteQueen to return arraylist include Objects have QueenPos like {0,1,2,0},{1,1,2,0},{2,1,2,0},{3,1,2,0} but the array list return me a objects have QueenPos like this {3,1,2,0} ,  {3,1,2,0} ,  {3,1,2,0} ,  {3,1,2,0} @Prerna-Gupta

Comment: @Duha Would be much better if you edit the question and clarify it with the examples, instead of using comments. The question should stand by itself, without people having to read the comments. Delete the comment once you've added the information to the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This overwrite is happening because you are making changes in same  `QueenPos[]` object of `Queen` object every time.

Example :

`First Iteration` :

You have fetched queenPos[] in g[] which is {0,1,2,0} and it got updated to {0,1,2,0}

`Second Iteration`

g[] = QueenPos[] = {0,1,2,0} and it got updated to {1,1,2,0} .

Since g[] reference to queenpos[] so whatever changes you do in g[] they get reflected to queenPos[] as well (g[] is shallow copy of queenPos[]) .

So , after first iteration your queenPos[] got changed to {1,1,2,0} , since you are storing `g[]` which is indirectly queenPos[] in your array list `gen` and it got changed to {1,1,2,0} . So, this value gets updated at 0 and 1 index of array list.

So in order to solve this issue you can create a new (deep) copy of this `QueenPos[]` object in each `for` loop iteration by using either of the method [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193402/creating-new-array-with-contents-from-old-array-while-keeping-the-old-array-stat.)

Here is he updated code for doing the same :

### Code :

```
 public static ArrayList<ExpressionTree> GenarateQueen (ExpressionTree q,int col){
            ArrayList<ExpressionTree> gen=new ArrayList<ExpressionTree>() ;


            for (int i = 0; i < q.QueenPos.length; i++) {
                int g[] = new int[q.QueenPos.length];
                System.arraycopy(q.QueenPos, 0, g, 0, 4); 
                g[col]=i;
                gen.add(i,new ExpressionTree(g));
                int a[]=gen.get(i).QueenPos;
                int r=0;
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < gen.size(); i++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < gen.get(i).QueenPos.length; k++) {
                  System.out.print(" | "+gen.get(i).QueenPos[k]+" | ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }               
            return gen;
   }
```

### Ouput

```
 | 0 |  | 1 |  | 2 |  | 0 | 
 | 1 |  | 1 |  | 2 |  | 0 | 
 | 2 |  | 1 |  | 2 |  | 0 | 
 | 3 |  | 1 |  | 2 |  | 0 |
```

Through this line `System.arraycopy(q.QueenPos, 0, g, 0, 4);` I am creating new array `g` everytime from original `queenPos[]`, instead of modifying in the same `queenPos[]`.

And, also as per the comment you can remove `static` fields from your constructor as well. . So updated Queen object should be :

```
public class Queen{


            int QueenPos[];
            int her;
            int N;


            public ExpressionTree(int[] queenPos) {
                this.QueenPos=queenPos;
                this.her = getHer();
                this.N=getQueenPos().length;
            }

            public ExpressionTree() {

            }

            public int getHer() {
                return her;
            }

            public int[] getQueenPos() {
              return QueenPos;
            }

            public  void setQueenPos(int queenPos[]) {
              QueenPos = queenPos;
            } 
}
```